# Laravel 5 - Display different views based on database query

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have the following database design
[image: Database design]

I have several different Documents I want a user to be able to create.  Each document has its own view for the creation of the document, or the editing.

If the document they are trying to create has already been created, they should see the edit page for that document.

At the moment, I have the following

```
public function create(Project $project)
{
    $documentTypesCreated =
        $project->document()
            ->join('document_type', 'documents.id', '=', 'document_type.documentId')
            ->select('document_type.documentId', 'document_type.name')
            ->get();

    $documentLink = $_GET['documentType'];

    if($documentTypesCreated->isEmpty()){
        return View::make($documentLink.'Doc.create', compact('project'));
    } else {
        foreach($documentTypesCreated as $documentName) {
            if($documentName->name != $documentLink) {
                return View::make($documentLink.'Doc.create', compact('project'));
            } else {
                $document = Document::find($documentName->documentId);
                return View::make($documentLink.'Doc.edit', compact('project', 'document'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Breaking this up, I am doing the following:
Firstly, I get all the Documents that have been created for a Project

```
$documentTypesCreated =
    $project->document()
        ->join('document_type', 'documents.id', '=', 'document_type.documentId')
        ->select('document_type.documentId', 'document_type.name')
        ->get();
```

I then get the Document the user is trying to create from the URL

```
$documentLink = $_GET['documentType'];
```

So lets say that the query returns that this Project has
DocumentA
DocumentB

And the documentLink shows that I am trying to create DocumentB.

Because DocumentB has already been created, I need the edit page for this Document.  Firstly, I check if the query returned and Documents

```
if($documentTypesCreated->isEmpty()){
    return View::make($documentLink.'Doc.create', compact('project'));
} else {

}
```

If it didnt, it will show the create page for the chosen Document.  If it did, the else statement will kick in.
Within the else statement, I loop through all the Documents the query returned

```
foreach($documentTypesCreated as $documentName) {

}
```

I then do the following, and this is where my logic is failing

```
if($documentName->name != $documentLink) {
    return View::make($documentLink.'Doc.create', compact('project'));
} else {
    $document = Document::find($documentName->documentId);
    return View::make($documentLink.'Doc.edit', compact('project', 'document'));
}
```

If the document Name from the query is not equal to the document I am trying to create, then I show the create page for that Document.  Otherwise, I show the edit page.

Now lets get back to where I chose DocumentB.  I know that I have already created this Document, so I should see its edit page.  However, because DocumentA is the first result returned in the query, the above statement looks like the following

```
if("DocumentA" != "DocumentB") {
    return View::make($documentLink.'Doc.create', compact('project'));
} else {
    $document = Document::find($documentName->documentId);
    return View::make($documentLink.'Doc.edit', compact('project', 'document'));
}
```

So it is going to show the create page for DocumentB, not the edit page.  If DocumentB was the first result returned, then the edit page would be displayed.

I Hope this makes sense.  How can I get it displaying the correct view for the document?

Thanks

Comment: Let me know if my answer help :) !

Comment: Hi, I made some progress since, so I have updated the original question as to where I am having difficulties.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

## Controller

Base on your query  - you may set these variables manually

```
$create = true; 
$edit = false;
```

**Logic**

```
if ($query == 'any logic') {
    $create = true; 
    $edit = false; 
}else{
    $create = false; 
    $edit = edit; 
    
}
```

Then, send them over to your view.

---

## View

```
@if($create == true)

//.. Show Create Form 

@else

// .. Show Edit Form 

@stop
```

Then, your view will render base the result of your query. I hope this help !